# Changed CPU and system doesn't boot. Put back old CPU, it doesn't boot either

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

Ok, this is my motherboard: GA-945PL-DS3 (rev. 2.0).

When I bought this PC it came with Intel Pentium 4 3.0 GHz.
Now, I bought new processor Intel Core 2 Duo E6700 2 x 2.66 GHz. I removed old CPU and I placed new CPU and nothing happened. I heard few beeps but system failed to boot. When I put back old CPU again (Pentium 4), system failed to boot again. No beeps, no BIOS, only black screen. Fan works and power is on but system fails to start. Can someone tell me what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow proper ESD precautions?  What motherboard do you have exactly?  I can't even find your processor on Intel's website.  Those Pentium 4 products I do find cannot be replaced with a Core 2 Duo product.  Who told you the `Intel Pentium 4 3.0 GHz` could be replaced with a `Core 2 Duo` because you got bad advice.

Comment: @Ramhound Guy in service that sold me CPU. Unfortunatelly, I'm an utter noob when it comes to hardware.

Comment: He sold you something you can't use.  It also likely damaged your existing hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you specify what hardware it could damage?

Comment: Core2Duo and P4 3Ghz both came in a LGA 775 socket configuration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775

Comment: You put an incapability CPU in the socket any number of things could have gone wrong.  They might have been the same socket but there was specific power requirements for it to work.  Most LGA775 motherboards purchase in 2004 didn't support the 2006 Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Remove the original CPU again and reseat it. Then power on and see what happens.

Comment: According to this website my motherboard supports E6700: http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Gigabyte/GA-945PL-DS3(rev._2.0).html

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2409#ov states "only supports 800 front side bus" the new processor is 1066 FSB (http://ark.intel.com/products/27251/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6700-4M-Cache-2_66-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb)

Comment: You might need to clear the CMOS (unplug  power, remove battery, wait 1 minute)

Comment: Did you upgrade the BIOS before you did this update? Update the question itself.  You should have provided the motherboard information from the start.

Comment: @Ramhound No I didn't. And what about that hardware damage?

Comment: @brano - What about it?  I can't predict what it could have done exactly only it could have happen.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for tips guys. I think it would be the best to send my PC to some service.